# JTokenType.Date is not matching in switch case

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have the following code snippet,

```cs
private static string CreateFilter(JProperty property)
{
    if (property?.Value == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    switch (property.Value.Type)
    {
        case JTokenType.Array:
            return CreateFilterForArray(property.Name, (JArray)property.Value);

        case JTokenType.Object:
            return CreateFilterForObject(property.Name, (JObject)property.Value);
        case JTokenType.Date:
            Console.WriteLine("date");
            return null;

        case JTokenType.String:
            return CreateFilterForString(property.Name, ((JValue)property.Value).Value);

        case JTokenType.Integer:
            return CreateFilterForInteger(property.Name, ((JValue)property.Value).Value);
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException($"No known way to handle json value with type of {property.Value.Type}");
    }
}
```

When the `property.Value` has a value of `{05/22/2019}`, instead of matching to 
`case JTokenType.Date:` it matches to `case JTokenType.String:` 
I guess this is probably because of the format expected for `JTokenType.Date` is different than what I'm providing to it. 
What is the format expected by `JTokenType.Date` ?.
Is there any way to match the date format I have, to the `JTokenType.Date` ?

Comment: Can you share how the `JProperty` was originally populated -- i.e. a [mcve]?  `property.Value.Type` is set at the time the `JToken` hierarchy is parsed.  (By the way, `JProperty.Value` is never null; when the JSON contains a `null` token it becomes a non-null `JValue` with type `JTokenType.Null` when parsed.)

Comment: Try changing the Format of the date to be something like `2019-05-22T00:00:00` and make sure that the date is passed in the same format i.e. `date+timeStamp` else it will not be identified as `JToken`.

Comment: Related: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm

Comment: @dbc The current value I'm giving is `{"Date": "05/21/2019"}` also tried `{"Date": "2012-03-19T07:22Z"}` (as provided in newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm). It didn't worked in both case.

Comment: Looks like `"2012-03-19T07:22Z"` needs to be **`"2012-03-19T07:22:00Z"`** (i.e. with seconds included), see https://dotnetfiddle.net/60FrIJ for a demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for [@dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc)'s comment, I send the date in `"2012-03-19T07:22:00Z"` and it is now recognizing as `JTokenType.Date`